# Increment and Decrement Operators output

Tags: java, increment

Hi i'm new at programming, stack overflow and i have a question

```
int i = 0;
int j ;
j = ++i;
System.out.println(i);
```

in this code why is the output 1 and not 0 as (i) should be? why is it connected to (j) value?

Comment: Why do you think the output should be 0? Increment operators modify the value they operate on

Comment: It's `1` because you incremented it from `0`, and `0 + 1 == 1`.

Comment: I mean (j) should be 1 because j=++i not int (I) @user16320675